# Cancel/Timeout Ping in BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, backgroundworker, ping

What I'm doing is running the below code in a backgroundworker. My problem is the Ping.send() method takes several seconds (6-8) to reply back with a Timeout. What I would like to do is, either cancel/kill the Ping.Send method after x amount of time OR, if it's possible have it timeout on it's own but in 2-3 seconds. I played around with a timer but i wasn't able to get that to work. Anyone have a suggestion on how i should do this?

Edit: When the reply is successful it's replies back in a decent amount of time which I'm okay with.

```
Ping ping = new Ping();
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
PingOptions pingOpt = new PingOptions(128, true);
try
{              
    PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(PCName, 10, buffer, pingOpt);
    if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
    else                                 
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}
catch
{
    //Do Something
}
```

Comment: You're *already* providing a timeout value...

Comment: Yup. I'm not trying to kill the Background worker. Just the Ping.Send() if that's possible.

Comment: @HiTech Which you're already doing...I fail to see the problem.

Comment: I suppose if the timeout value i supplied is supposed to Timeout after 10ms. Then the Timeout is not worknig... Because i sit waiting for about 8 seconds pinging a single computer on my LAN. @Servy Do you see the problem now?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the SendAsync methods, which would make this easier to handle (indeed, if the BackgroundWorker is just there for this ping, then you might be able to dispose of it altogether.

Comment: While there may be some advantages to doing this asynchronously, both the synchronous and asynchronous methods already provide support for a timeout, so there is no *need* to do this.

Comment: @Servy - good point - I was thinking he wanted a cancel button of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

You are *already* providing a timeout.  The second parameter in all overloads that have at least two parameters is a timeout (in milliseconds).  You're using a 10 millisecond timeout.